# making mesos console available through rproxy (nginx)

Tags: nginx, mesos

I want to make my mesos console running inside on 10.10.2.1:5050 available on te outside of my setup using nginx. I configured nginx as follows:

```
server {
        listen   8082;
        server_name mgmt.company.com;

        location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://10.10.2.1:5050;

         }
```

This works in calling mgmt.company.com:8082

But then pressing a link in the mesos console, like "sandbox" for a running job gets an error in the mesos console like:

```
Failed to connect to slave '35c8cd5c-6105-4cf1-afc1-d506d767dfa7-S0' on '/slave/35c8cd5c-6105-4cf1-afc1-d506d767dfa7-S0/'.
Potential reasons:
The slave is not accessible
The slave timed out or went offline
```

Whereas this works if I do not use a proxy and just address (in my VPN ito the the infra, so I can directly reach 10.10.2.1) 10.10.2.1:5050 so it must be an nginx config thing.

No logging in nginx error log, in nginx access log I see for this call:

```
xx.xx.xx.xxx - - [08/Oct/2016:20:45:23 +0200] "GET /slave/35c8cd5c-6105-4cf1-afc1-d506d767dfa7-S0/slave(1)/state?jsonp=angular.callbacks._1 HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "http://mgmt.company.com:8082/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50" "-"
```

What should I add to my nginx config to get the stuff resolved OK ??
Any idea ?

Thanks !
R.

Comment: To make UI fully operable you must be able to connect with every slave. Take a look at [MESOS-2129](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-2129)